# Linear regression AIC and Randomisation Test

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic

The problem is that I used AIC as the criterion for model selection and that gives me a model with 3 parameters (the model has the lowest AIC).

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3$$

However, the coefficients of 2 parameters are close to zero. I conducted bootstrapping by resampling observations in the original dataset, and get 95% confidence intervals for each coefficients. None of confidence interval includes 0.

Then I performed Randomisation test by only resampling y (break the relationship of Y and other covariates) with the null hypothesis that Y and other covariates have no relationship (beta1=beta2=beta3=0). I expect to see the coefficients in my original model are all significant in this Randomisation Test, however, the 2 coefficients that are close to zero I mentioned before are insignificant this time in Randomisation Test. This makes me fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Now the question is should I drop those two covariates that are insignificant in Randomisation Test or stick to original model and rely on AIC?

Comment: Did you check the standard error of estimated regression coefficients?

Comment: @a_statistician, every coefficients are significant in T test. I used R and summary() just performed T test automatically, and P value for T test is 0.01 and 0.03. But I don't think we can assume the assumptions of T test are satisfied?

Comment: Which t test assumptions are not met?

Comment: @a_statistician umm I don't know. Because there is divergence of T test and Randomisation Test... so I think it's because T test assumptions are not met?? Is there any way to check? I just plotted the QQ plot of one parameter's coefficients generated from bootstrapping, there is a marked skewness...

Comment: Check the if Xs and Y have other non-linear relation, normality of residues and homogeneity of residuals by different scatterplots of residual vs predicted Y.

Comment: I would say that you shouldn't rely on statistical significance to pick your variables.